# Replace ActionBar icon with text

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to be able to use text instead of the regular icon in the action bar. The image below from the Contacts app that's built in shows exactly what is desired.

[image]

setIcon() doesn't have any option for taking a String as a parameter so I don't know what to do.

Comment: hide the icon then it will look like this but it makes t hard to click on the back arrow

Comment: I want the back arrow and the text to appear as all one button as in the Contacts app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
actionBar.setTitle("Asdfasdfasdf");
actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Is it possible to have the above but also have a title centered in the middle of the action bar also?

Comment: take a look on my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
private void setupActionBar(Activity activity)
{
    View v = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.action_bar_layout, null);
    assert v != null;
    Button actionBarMenu = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.actionBarMenu);
    actionBarMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }
    });

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    ActionBar actionBar = activity.getActionBar();

    assert actionBar != null;

    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    actionBar.setCustomView(v);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
}
```

And action_bar_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="menu"
        android:id="@+id/actionBarMenu"
        android:textColor="#f5c046"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:id="@+id/actionBarTitle"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="125dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```